Saussure and substance
I am wondering where Saussure identifies the substance of language. I have my own interpretation and would like to know your thoughts. First let me give you a rundown of what I think I've figured out so far:
Every time we speak (parole), there are two amorphous masses facing each other: noises and thoughts. Elements within them are only distinguishable by a system (langue) that cuts each side into distinct signs (signifier + signified). Now since these signs, as a system, are merely idealistic and non-material, it is not possible to subscribe any substance to them. No actual sound nor concept can be "inscribed" within them, since outside of parole, outside of the amorphous masses, they don't actually exist. This is evident by the fact that no concrete occurrence is ever identical in its usage. Thus, the system of la langue can only ever provide a form. This form is achieved by its structure: A sound or concept is only whatever its borders (constituted by its neighbors) allow it to be. Any concrete sound/concept can only be re-identified by the fact that it is not another one. Concepts and sounds are "vibrating" (my words) between different occurrences, rendering any positive identification useless. The only possible identification is by means of exclusion: as long as the "vibration" does not "hit" into a surrounding sound/concept, it can be understood as what it is.
Now I'm not sure where substance exists in this picture. So far, no literature I've read (only secondary) mentions it explicitly, but by my conclusion, substance is the concrete occurrence of signs within the amorphous masses. Basically, langue is whatever remains after stripping away any particular, practical, concrete usage of language (i.e. parole). Any thought of a "tree" and any spoken word of this sound is a bit different in each and everyone of us, so whatever remains as an abstraction can never contain an exact, ideal representation of it. The system of language can only ever be form, and we are the ones giving it substance through parole.
Is this a stretch, or is it a correct paraphrasing of Saussure's ideas?

See Louis Hjelmslev's theory for a development of Saussure's sign model, based on signifier and signified, into a four terms model: expression and  content, and between form and substance. The combinations of the four would distinguish between form of content, form of expression, substance of content, and substance of expression.

This question is similar to: Have I got Saussure's distinction between the form and substance right?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also Jørgen Dines Johansen's Form vs. Substance into Thomas A. Sebeok etc (editor), Encyclopedic Dictionary of Semiotics Tome I (1986), page 269.

According to the traditional reading (that I suppose was quite familiar to Saussure) we have form (essence), matter and substance (the individual). Thus, the expression is substance (carved out from the unlimted continuum of sound) and also the content is substance (carved out from the unlimited continuum of thought). They are linked by form as two faces of a coin: "the combination of expression (signifiiant) and content (signifié) in the sign produces a form, not a substance ( Cours, p. 157)."

@MauroALLEGRANZA thank you, I think your last comment confirms my interpretation, which was: "substance is the concrete occurrence of signs within the amorphous masses." and "The system of language can only ever be form, and we are the ones giving it substance through parole." I think these statements essentially mirror your explanation (although my use of the terms 'sign' and 'parole' in this context may be a bit idiosyncratic).

@MauroALLEGRANZA so what my essential understanding is: if you strip away any concrete usage of language and only look at its organization, the only thing that remains is a substance-less structure of signs that have no distinct meaning other than their position within this structure.

"langue is whatever remains after stripping away any particular, practical, concrete usage of language (i.e. parole)" I was under the impression that parole is actual usage (the intersection of actual idiolects), and that langue was the abstraction across idiolects as a sort of measure of central tendency. That the langue seeks to characterize parole as a grammar and mental model of actual practice. No?
